How do i handle an SMTPConnectError? I tried connecting to my Gmail account to send a message but was not successful
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\pc\Downloads\stock-news-extrahard-start\stock-news-extrahard-start\main.py", line 94, in 
connection = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\smtplib.py", line 258, in init
raise SMTPConnectError(code, msg)
smtplib.SMTPConnectError: (421, b'Service not available')
This is the error message im getting ans im trying to connect to my gmail. Ive already created a 2 step verification code some days ago. I created another one because i felt it might have expired. But ight now nothing is working. Please who can help me out
This is the code in python:
connection = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
connection.starttls()

connection.login(user=my_email, password=password)
connection.sendmail(from_addr=my_email,
                    to_addrs="donatusudeani@outlook.com",
                    msg=f"Subject: {STOCK}: {stock_icon[1]}{abs_percentage_change}%\n\n{message_to_send}")

